# How to find out if a server uses VPS or dedicated hosting?

Tags: vps, cloud-hosting, dedicated-hosting

How can I find out whether or not a server is hosted on VPS or dedicated hosting?

I'm trying to find out about a cloud hosting service I use. It has some other services too and their IP address similar. Only last digit is different and the 2 othesr have different IP addresses.  Their IP address's last digit is consecutive to the cloud server.

I know there might not be much difference if it is VPS or dedicated, but I want to know.

Comment: If you're a customer of theirs I can't imagine a good reason not to just call and ask.

Comment: I emailed they didnt reply